# Scala pattern matching multiple combinator parsers results

Tags: scala, parsing, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Having a List[String] and several parsers I want to pattern match each String from the List to parsers. So it'd look like this (Warning, pseudo-code):

```
myStringList.map{
  case MyParser.keyword => keyword match {
    case KeywordParser.keyword1 => //it's special keyword1
    case KeywordParser.keyword2 => //special treatment for keyword2
    case NotSpecial => //it's a usual command
  }
  case MyParser.stringValue => //etc...
}
```

Why would I want to do so?

I'm parsing a simple script line, that contains "strings" and $(keywords). Some of the keywords are special and need to be treated separately.
Currently I have only one special keyword, so I'm using chained parseAll and match, but that doesn't feel right.

So, how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bet I had a short-circuit in my brain, because I woke up next morning and realised, that all I need is a couple of parsers, some case classes and a pair of pattern matchers. So the solution to my problem looks like this (pseudo-code):

```
case class SpecialKeyword1(value: String)
case class SpecialKeyword2(value: String)
...
case class SpecialKeywordN(value: String)
case class SimpleKeyword(value: String)

object MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers{
  def expression: Parser[Any] = ...
  def keyword1: Parser[SpecialKeyword1] = ...
  def keyword2: ...
  ...
  def simplekeyword: Parser[SimpleKeyword] = ...
}

object Main {
  def parseScript(inputScript: String): String = {
    MyParser.parseAll(MyParser.expression, inputScript) match {
      case Success(result, _) => {
        case SpecialKeyword1(val) => ...
        case SpecialKeyword2(val) => ...
        ...
        case SimpleKeyword(val) => ...
        case str: String => ...
      }
      case Failure(_, _) => "Parsing Failure"
      case Error(_, _) => "Parsing Error"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really supported, but you can do it like this:

```
  val parseKeyword: PartialFunction[String, ... ] {
    case KeywordParser.keyword1 => //it's special keyword1
    case KeywordParser.keyword2 => //special treatment for keyword2
    case NotSpecial => //it's a usual command    
  }

  myStringList.map{
    case x@MyParser.keyword if parseKeyword.isDefinedAt(x) => parseKeyword(x)
    case MyParser.stringValue => //etc...
  }
```